# getting active on server fault

Tags: discussion, openid

Will i lose any data in stackoverflow if i say okay to "migrate user" option in becoming active on server fault? 
It is happening because I am using the same openid and its smart enough to recognize that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's because it's the same OpenID and no, you won't lose data but remember Reputation does not move across with you by design.

Discuss these issues here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't lose any data.  The two sites are independent in terms of reputation, questions, answers, etc.  Migrating means you'll start with 101 reputation (if your current reputation is high enough) instead of 1.